# Cannot see OpenStreetMap, Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, openstreetmap

I would like to add OSM to my website (in Ruby on Rails), so I've exported following html code from their site:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-109.3359375%2C56.84897198026975%2C25.3125%2C84.38877975103257&amp;layer=mapnik&amp;marker=76.23088818107027%2C-42.076958649999995" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe><br/>

<small><a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=76.23&amp;mlon=-42.08#map=3/76.23/-42.08">see more</a></small>
```

and I've put it into

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
              //here
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, that there is only empty rectangle, without map, but when I click "see more" I'm redirected to OSM site with big map.
What can cause, that I can't see map on my site?

Edit:
I've just seen, that it only doesn't work only in desktop browser, when I use my mobile phone is ok.

Comment: I am able to see the map in Chrome and Firefox desktop version.

Comment: Can you tell me, which version you have installed?

Comment: Any errors in the developer console?

Comment: No, there is nothing

Comment: Works for me with Firefox 45 and Chromium 52.